# Straight Chain Alk*nes without Order

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics, chemistry

This is much like my [earlier challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/103105/number-of-straight-chain-alknes-of-given-length), except, this time, order *doesn't* matter.

A straight-chain alk*ne is defined as a sequence of carbon atoms connected by single (alkane), double (alkene), or triple bonds (alkyne), (implicit hydrogens are used.) Carbon atoms can only form 4 bonds, so no carbon atom may be forced to have more than four bonds. A straight-chain alk*ne can be represented as a list of its carbon-carbon bonds.

These are some examples of valid (not necessarily distinct) straight-chain alk*nes:

```
[]       CH4              Methane
[1]      CH3-CH3          Ethane
[2]      CH2=CH2          Ethene
[3]      CH≡CH            Ethyne
[1,1]    CH3-CH2-CH3      Propane
[1,2]    CH3-CH=CH2       Propene
[1,3]    CH3-C≡CH         Propyne
[2,1]    CH2=CH-CH3       Propene
[2,2]    CH2=C=CH2        Allene (Propadiene)
[3,1]    CH≡C-CH3         Propyne 
[1,1,1]  CH3-CH2-CH2-CH3  Butane
...
```

While these are not, as at least one carbon atom would have more than 4 bonds:

```
[2,3]
[3,2]
[3,3]
...
```

Two straight-chain alk*nes, `p` and `q` are considered equivalent if `p` is `q` reversed, or `p` is `q`.

```
[1] = [1]
[1,2] = [2,1]
[1,3] = [3,1]
[1,1,2] = [2,1,1]
[1,2,2] = [2,2,1]
```

Your task is to create a program/function that, given a positive integer `n`, outputs/returns the **number** of valid straight-chain alk*nes of exactly `n` carbon atoms in length.

## Specifications/Clarifications

- You must handle `1` correctly by returning `1`.
- Alk*nes like `[1,2]` and `[2,1]` are *NOT* considered distinct.
- Output is the *length* of a list of all the possible alk*nes of a given length.
- You do *not* have to handle `0` correctly.

## Test Cases:

```
1 => 1
2 => 3
3 => 4
4 => 10
5 => 18
6 => 42
```

This is code golf, so the lowest byte count wins!

Comment: Are we supposed to *guess* what the correct number is? If not, can you specify how we figure it out? Specifically: Is *every* sequence (of the given length) that doesn't contain two adjacent numbers that sum to more than 4 valid? If so, can you [edit] that info in the question post?

Comment: Too much similar to [Number of Straight-Chain Alk\*nes of given length](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/103105/number-of-straight-chain-alknes-of-given-length)

Comment: That help at all?

Comment: @JungHwanMin Why do you think so? I'm not seeing an obvious way to reuse any of the non-brute force answers from that challenge.

Comment: @MartinEnder The answer is simply (# of straight-chain alk\*nes)/2 + (# of symmetrical straight-chain alk\*nes)/2

Comment: Oh, and # of symmetrical straight-chain alk\*nes is 3^floor(n/2), right (where n is the length)?

Comment: @MartinEnder (# of symmetrical straight-chain alk\*nes) has the recurrence relation `a(n) = 2*a(n-2) + a(n-4) - a(n-6)` with initial conditions `a(0) = 1`, `a(1) = 3`, `a(2) = 2`, `a(3) = 6`, `a(4) = 5`, and `a(5) = 14`. That's really similar to `a(n) = 2*a(n-1) + a(n-2) - a(n-3)` from the other question.

Comment: The recurrence equation for this problem is `a(n) = 2*a(n-1) + 3*a(n-2) - 5*a(n-3) - a(n-4) - 2a(n-6) + 3*a(n-7) + a(n-8) - a(n-9)` with `a(0) = 1, a(1) = 3, a(2) = 4, a(3) = 10, a(4) = 18, a(5) = 42, a(6) = 84, a(7) = 192, a(8) = 409`

Comment: The only problem with that is `a(1)` should be `1`, `a(2)` should be `3`, etc. as noted in the test cases.

Comment: @ZacharyT My bad... but still, my point is that this challenge is too similar to the other one.

Comment: @JungHwanMin I think that's sufficiently different for it not to be a duplicate (otherwise the original would have been a duplicate of Fibonacci). Whether it adds something interesting over the previous challenge I don't know, but I wouldn't close it.

Comment: Deriving an answer to this question from an answer to the previous one without exploiting any structure to the answer (e.g. filtering a list of constructed chains) requires case splitting: if the previous answer's sequence is `a(n)` and this one is `b(n)` then a bit of work with @JungHwanMin's recurrences shows that `2 b(2n) = a(2n) + a(n+1) - a(n-1)` and `2 b(2n+1) = a(2n+1) + a(n+2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## JavaScript (ES6), 107 bytes

```
A=n=>n>9?2*A(n-1)+3*A(n-2)+3*A(n-7)+A(n-8)-5*A(n-3)-A(n-4)-2*A(n-6)-A(n-9):[0,1,3,4,10,18,42,84,192,409][n]
```

Recursive solution, using the recurrence relation that was pointed out in the comments of the question. Execution time rises much quicker than the input (complexity of `O(9^N)` if I'm not mistaken), so be careful with values higher than 20.

Comment: Winner by default.

Answer (score 1):

## MMIX, <s>108</s> 92 bytes (<s>27</s> 23 instrs)

Works mod \$2^{63}\$, because it uses the two-part recurrence instead of the one-part, due to the two-part recurrence being much easier to compute.

(jxd)

```
00000000: e3010001 e3020001 e3030003 e3040001  ẉ¢¡¢ẉ£¡¢ẉ¤¡¤ẉ¥¡¢
00000010: e3050003 e3060006 67050002 67060005  ẉ¦¡¤ẉ©¡©g¦¡£g©¡¦
00000020: 27000001 28ff0302 26ffff01 c1010200  '¡¡¢(”¤£&””¢Ḋ¢£¡
00000030: c1020300 c103ff00 28ff0605 26ffff04  Ḋ£¤¡Ḋ¤”¡(”©¦&””¥
00000040: 66040005 66050006 660600ff 5b00fff5  f¥¡¦f¦¡©f©¡”[¡”ṫ
00000050: 22000104 3f000001 f8010000           "¡¢¥?¡¡¢ẏ¢¡¡
```

Disassembly and explanation:

```
alkns   SET   $1,1          // a(0)
        SET   $2,1          // a(1)
        SET   $3,3          // a(2)
        SET   $4,1          // b(0)/b(1)
        SET   $5,3          // b(2)
        SET   $6,6          // b(4)
        CSOD  $5,$0,2       // b(3), use if n is odd
        CSOD  $6,$0,5       // b(5), use if n is odd
0H      SUBU  $0,$0,1       // loop: n--
        2ADDU $255,$3,$2    // a(n+1) = 2a(n) + a(n-1)
        SUBU  $255,$255,$1  // - a(n-2)
        SET   $1,$2         // and shift
        SET   $2,$3         // values of a
        SET   $3,$255       // down
        2ADDU $255,$6,$5    // b(n+2) = 2b(n) + b(n-2)
        SUBU  $255,$255,$4  // - b(n-4)
        CSOD  $4,$0,$5      // shift values of b down
        CSOD  $5,$0,$6      // if n is odd
        CSOD  $6,$0,$255    // (happens once if n started at 2 or 3)
        PBNZ  $0,0B         // if(n) goto loop
        ADDU  $0,$1,$4      // r(n) = (a(n) + b(n))
        SRU   $0,$0,1       // ÷ 2
        POP   1,0           // return r(n)
```