# Consecutive Composite Numbers

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory

## Challenge

Generate \$n-1\$ **consecutive** composite numbers using this prime gap formula

$$n!+2,n!+3,...,n!+n$$

**Input**

An integer \$n\$ such that \$3 \leq n \leq 50 \$.

**Output**

Sequence of \$n-1\$ consecutive composite numbers.

## Example

**Input**

```
3
```

**Output**

```
8
9
```

## Rules

- Output should be in integer format.

## Test Cases

For \$n > 20\$, the results are very BIG integers (greater than 64-bits) and will most likely require a language that natively supports large numbers or a 3rd party library to handle them.

| n | \$n-1\$ consecutive composites |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 8 9 |
| 5 | 122 123 124 125 |
| 21 | 51090942171709440002 51090942171709440003 51090942171709440004 51090942171709440005 51090942171709440006 51090942171709440007 51090942171709440008 51090942171709440009 51090942171709440010 51090942171709440011 51090942171709440012 51090942171709440013 51090942171709440014 51090942171709440015 51090942171709440016 51090942171709440017 51090942171709440018 51090942171709440019 51090942171709440020 51090942171709440021 |

Comment: Do you happen to be a student at Northeastern University?

Comment: Also, the formula gives n-1 composite numbers. (I asked because this appears on a homework I'm grading that was due yesterday)

Comment: May I output the numbers in reverse or in an arbitrary order?

Comment: Your last comment makes me wonder: if supporting large integers is a strict requirement (which doesn't sound like a good idea), it should be explicitly mentioned in the challenge.

Comment: Please note that "making the challenge trickier by requiring a bignum" is one example of [unnecessary fluff](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9384/78410) and therefore discouraged. Check out the fifth rule on [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/210071/78410) (which is the implicit default on this site).

Comment: So, to be clear: do answers need to support arbiitrarily large integers, or is it acceptable if the results become inexact for large inputs due floating-point issues or maximum representable values? Voting to close until clarified

Comment: It would be interesting if anyone has a method for consecutive composites other than the factorial solution (or brute force)

Comment: Does n=1 have to output nothing, or is it undefined behavior?

Comment: I wouldn't say my math ability is above anyone else's here :p It would be much clearer if you defined how large the maximum n to be supported is.

Comment: I only ask because n! is much larger than the smallest consecutive composite values: https://oeis.org/A008950 For example, for n=50, the 50 numbers following 738832927927 (well within a 64 bit int) work. I don't think there's any nice way of computing these, though.

Comment: Actually I read the OEIS gap size wrong. https://oeis.org/A204665 is for gaps of size 52. So the following 50 numbers after 19609 are composite.

Comment: @qwr Looks like the [CRT Method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4847837/consecutive-composite-numbers-using-the-chinese-remainder-theorem) can be used to generate \$n\$ consecutive composite numbers but is more complicated than the factorials formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ḋ+!
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hji5txf///xsZAgA)**

A monadic Link that accepts a positive integer, \$n\$, and yields a list of the \$n-1\$ consecutive integers.

#### How?

```
Ḋ+! - Link: integer, n
Ḋ   - dequeue {n}      -> [2, 3, 4, ..., n]
  ! - {n} factorial    -> n!
 +  - add (vectorises) -> [2+n!, 3+n!, 4+n!, ..., n+n!]
```

Answer (score 5):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 5 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
1↓⍳+!
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=M3zUNvlR72ZtRQA&f=S1Mw5kpTMAViI0MA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog-extended&m=train&n=f)

A tacit function that takes an integer on the right and returns an array of n-1 composite numbers.

#### Explanation

```
    ! ⍝ factorial
   +  ⍝ plus
  ⍳   ⍝ range
1↓    ⍝ drop the first
```

There are actually two other permutations of these five characters that produce the same result.
See if you can find them. ;)

### 6 bytes, outputs full numbers under \$10^{34}\$

```
⍕1↓⍳+!
```

[Try it!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=03jUN9UtCEgEBGg@aptgaGRhrmBsAgA&c=e9Q7VVHb8FHb5Ee9mwE&f=S1Mw5kpTMAViI0MA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog-extended&m=train&n=f)
This requires adding `(⎕FR⎕PP)←1287 34` to the header to set the float and printing precision.

Comment: How many digits can Dyalog display. I attempted this in APL+WIN and like your answer it defaults to E notation for large numbers. That being the case with a 17 digit limit I could not display the true series as all results were the same for the 21 example i.e. 5.109094217170944E19 5.109094217170944E19 etc

Comment: To get an exact answer in Dyalog, you need to have `(⎕FR⎕PP)←1287 34` in the header and use `⍕`. I'll probably add this as 6 byte solution (usually, defining system variables like `⎕IO←` is not counted in bytes).

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2), 4 bytes

```
Ḣ?¡+
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyIiLCIiLCLhuKI/wqErIiwiIiwiMyJd)

```
Ḣ    # range(2, n+1)
   + # + 
 ?¡  # n!
```

Comment: 3 bytes # [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2) `Ṫ`, 3 bytes 

```
Ḣ?¡
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyLhuaoiLCIiLCLhuKI/wqEiLCIiLCI2Il0=)

Answer (score 4):

## [Funge-98](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Funge-98), 29 bytes

```
"HTMI"4(&:F2+v
\I_@#:-2\I.: <
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//9X8gjx9VQy0VCzcjPSLuOK8Yx3ULbSNYrx1LNSsPn/38iQCwA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 51 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:range((n<2or(f(n-1).stop-n)*n)-~n)[1-n:]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3jdNscxJzk1ISFfKsihLz0lM1NPJsjPKLNNI08nQNNfWKS_ILdPM0tfI0devyNKMNdfOsYqFaFdPyixQyFTLzFCAajXWMDDStCooy80o0tNI0MjU1IQphdgEA)

Returns a `range` object.

#### Original [Python](https://www.python.org), 56 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:[n*([*f(n-1),3][0]-2)+j+2for j in range(n-1)]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY9NCsIwFIT3PcUDN0ltQeumFLyCFyhFYs1rU5uXkr4g7r2FGzd6J29j_cPdDMPwzVzuw4lbR9frLTCm-SPHda_sbq-AipJiUcYoKF3KZFWViyrN5LybZ-g8dGAIvKJGv_Pq2z_PwKqDBsPgAwGqkbWHo5kggaFup4KhBiYzBC4i9M4CBqrZuX4EYwfnGXoftrWqWx1Na35abBxpKVBG0Ytv_vxlki1kMXhDLFAYKT9bfp-e)

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>52 51 47 46 45</s> 44 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,i=n)=>--n&&f(n,g=i*n)>console.log(n-~g)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9mC0QaeTqZtnmatna6unlqamlAbrptplaepl1yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaebl265v80DcM8TWsFZAlNa640DSOsosZYRU2xmwA0@D8A)

-1 byte from Arnauld/tsh

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 38 bytes by Mukundan314

```javascript
f=(n,i=n)=>--n?[...f(n,g=i*n),n-~g]:[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVYjTyfTNk/T1k5XN88@Wk9PLw0okm6bqZWnqZOnW5ceaxUd@z85P684PydVLyc/XSNNwzBPU9NaAVlM05oLVYkRYSXGhJWYEmERyDH/AQ)

Comment: Comparing BigInts with Numbers is fine, so you can just do `i>0`.

Comment: Maybe you need apply above comment again: `f=(n,i=n)=>--n&&f(n,g=i*n)>console.log(n-~g)`

Comment: [38 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVYjTyfTNk/T1k5XN88@Wk9PLw0okm6bqZWnqZOnW5ceaxUd@z85P684PydVLyc/XSNNwzBPU9NaAVlM05oLVYkRYSXGhJWYEmERyDH/AQ) by returning a list instead of outputting to console

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
RḊ+!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/o4Y4ubcX///8bGgEA)

Port of [Vyxal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269334/106959).

-1 byte thanks to [@emanresu A](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/100664/emanresu-a)

Explanation:

```
RḊ+!­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
RḊ    # ‎⁡[2 .. n]
  +!  # ‎⁢+ n!
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: [4](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z9IW/Hhjq7///8bGgEA)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
L¦¤!+
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f59CyQ0sUtf//NzIEAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/n0PLDi1R1P6v8z/aWMdUx8gwFgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
L      # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input]
 ¦     # Remove the first value to make the range [2,input]
  ¤    # Push the last item (without popping the list): the input
   !   # Take its factorial
    +  # Add it to each value in the list
       # (after which this list is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: `L¦DP+` also works for the same byte count.

Answer (score 3):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
╒╞\!+
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///R1EmPps6LUdT@/9@Yy5TLyBAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
╒      # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input]
 ╞     # Remove the first value to make the range [2,input]
  \    # Swap to push the (implicit) input
   !   # Take its factorial
    +  # Add it to each value in the list
       # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com), 10 bytes

```
[2...n]+n!
```

[Try it in Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/esdiw4nlkb?)

The simplest a solution can get, to be honest.

Comment: Nice creativity using desmos!

Comment: @vengy Desmos is literally math notation, so it's very good for challenges like this.

Comment: Does not work for n=1, but it's probably unreasonable to expect all answers to output nothing for that case.

Comment: @Tbw n=1 is now not a valid input

Comment: Nice answer! But taking input as a hardcoded variable (`n` in this case) is heavily discouraged by meta consensus. You will need to make it into a function (like `lambda` in Python) in order for this answer to conform with meta consensus. This can easily be done by adding `f(n)=` to the beginning of your code, at the cost of 5 bytes.

Comment: Another issue with this is that the numbers get inaccurate for large `n` due to floating point inaccuracies. As an example, `n=21` gives a list of all `51090942171709460000`. It is unclear whether or not OP is fine with such inaccuracies, but if not, this answer would technically be invalid.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 41 bytes

```perl
sub{@a=1..pop;$"='*';map$_+1+eval"@a",@a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZBRa4MwFIXf/RWHEFadwZlU12lw@Af2trd1iKVRBI2idkNKf7tLVrfzcC757j03JIMa23i9TArvaprT9K0flXTs@dTUjZ6l0y2gVbZOl9M1LzMeBEM/SEqy3eNOduVAC5/76qtsSV4Slpe3VTpVP7oOjD6wR/aKF4aEgYefbKOxpVwIA8XeWmQttvaM/ynB7Zi5AzEPkzCJBD/wg6lRaAQftGAQCAIIYVPe9TfYLS7VDPl3qWcPGXJayK2BvO5ngx5o5YJqePeGeQ2hT9hE7rCZirNSQ7u4ONoYM8WuZCA6tWHA0PSo/3J2iNiVN@fca1XM5kMbXcv1Bw)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 46 bytes

Prints the results in reverse order.

```javascript
n=>{for(p=i=n;--i;)p*=i;while(--n)print(p-~n)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcgxCoAwDADA3Vc4JkImEYQQ/1LEYkRiqKUOol@vgzfeFko456SeqYw1SjWZ7ngkcFExJlJG70T5WnVfgMjQk1oGp9fwqRF65PYv5CbCgPUD)

---

## JavaScript (ES11), 52 bytes

With BigInts.

```javascript
n=>{for(p=i=n;--i;)p*=i;while(--n)console.log(p-~n)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcmxCoNADADQ3a/omAgRtDiF9F/E3mnkSA4tdSj118/VwfW9ZfgO27hq/pD5O5QoxeT1i75CFhVjImXMtSjvs6YARIaj2@YpNMknyHQY/kuEpyE/roNcRehvtWsNywk)

Comment: [51 bytes](https://tio.run/##hcqxCgIxDIDh3afomMrlQMWpxBeRG8LZepGSlKt6g@irVxc3wfHn@y985zrOUq6odootUQPt2NPhkWyGQkIaECX4siYJyyQ5AqJ67sutTlDwpf7ZmI5DcAl22jn2wY2m1XLss53h06uv7//4dvN7aG8) for the ES11 version by using a [out argument](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4942/91267)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 7 bytes

```
!-<:$i:
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT0F9TQFWysFdR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxXFHXxkol0wrCu6miyZWanJGvkKZgXAFjmUJZJgqmKmkKRoYVELULFkBoAA)

Returns the list of numbers in reverse order. When given a bigint, outputs the exact numbers in bigint.

```
!-<:$i:    input: n, a positive integer
     i:    [-n, -n+1, ..., n]
  <:       n-1
    $      take first n-1 items from the list, i.e. [-n, ..., -2]
!          n!
 -         n! - each item of [-n, ..., -2]
           == [n!+n, n!+n-1, ..., n!+2]
```

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 8 bytes

```
!+-.{.i:
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT0F9TQFWysFdR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxQlFbV69aL9MKwr2posmVmpyRr5CmYFwBY5lCWSYKpippCkaGFRC1CxZAaAA)

Returns the list of numbers in the order given.

```
!+-.{.i:    input: n, a positive integer
      i:    [-n, -n+1, ..., n]
  -.        1-n
    {.      since 1-n is negative, take n-1 items from the end;
            [2, ..., n]
!+          add n! to each item of the list
```

Comment: I'm new to this site...and I always notice these "languages" generate really short code bytes. Are they specifically designed for code golf and how do they minimize the code so much? Thanks.

Comment: @vengy J is not a "golflang" (language created for golf); it just happens to be short quite a lot of the time. Jelly, Vyxal, and 05AB1E are some examples of often-used golflangs, all of which minimize code by utilizing all 256 byte values (as opposed to printable ASCII) loaded with built-in functions, among other things. Jelly specifically was inspired by J, and the other two are stack-based.

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](https://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Jan-14)</sup>, 9 bytes

```
↘1+/×.+1⇡
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__ZiDihpAg4oaYMSsvw5cuKzHih6EKCmYgMwpmIDUK)

Comment: [Seems there are many ways](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__4oaYMSsvw5cuKzHih6EgMworL8OXLuKGmDErMeKHoSAzCisvw5cuKzHihpgx4oehIDMKKy_Dly7ihpgy4oehKzEgMworL8OXLisx4pe04oqa4oehIDMK)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>69</s> 62 bytes

```python
lambda n:[i-~math.factorial(n)for i in range(1,n)]
import math
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcqxCsIwEIDhvU9xWxKJQi2CBPokbYdTG3vQXI70HFx89YhL3X5@Pnnrkrm7SqmxH@uK6fZA4DDQ8ZNQl1PEu@ZCuFp2MRcgIIaC/Jxt69lNDSXJReGH6w6Gzl/8uZ1CAyCFWK3byxDLS4Px9H@HaMn5bZbejGxc/QI)

Edit: changed `math.prod` to `math.factorial`, thanks to @l4m2

Comment: If you're going to be importing math, then you might as well use `math.factorial`

Comment: can you show me a shorter solution using `math.factorial` ?

Comment: [62](https://tio.run/##RcqxCsIwEIDhvU9xWxKJQi2CBPokbYdTG3vQXI70HFx89YhL3X5@Pnnrkrm7SqmxH@uK6fZA4DDQ8ZNQl1PEu@ZCuFp2MRcgIIaC/Jxt69lNDSXJReGH6w6Gzl/8uZ1CAyCFWK3byxDLS4Px9H@HaMn5bZbejGxc/QI)

Comment: No for-loop [needed](https://tio.run/##RcmxCsIwEIDhvU9xWxJJhVoECfRJ2g6nNvaguRzXOLj46hEX3X6@X15lzdxfRGscprphut4ROCjyY7HcvhOW9RjxVrISbpadG7uWw9xQkqwFvr/GrEBADGPvz/7UzaEBECUu1v3KEMuzBOPpb4doyfl9kcFMbFz9AA). Cf. @Albert.Lang's answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), <s>56</s> 54 bytes

```
[dlf*sf1-d0!=q]sq1sf?d1-sm[dlf2++p0=m1+dlm!=e]selqxlex
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/z86JSdNqzjNUDfFQNG2MLa40LA4zT7FULc4FyRjpK1dYGCba6idkpOraJsaW5yaU1iRk1rx/7@RIQA)

This solution isn't the most optimized, you could probably use less registers than I did here.

Answer (score 2):

## Google Sheets, 32 bytes

```cpp
=SORT(FACT(A1)+SEQUENCE(A1-1)+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

## C (gcc), 170 bytes

Using The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library

```
f(n){mpz_t f,t;mpz_init(f);mpz_init(t);mpz_set_ui(f,1);for(int i=1;i<=n;mpz_mul_ui(f,f,i++));for(int i=2;i<=n;mpz_add_ui(t,f,i),mpz_out_str(stdout,10,t),puts(""),i++);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDBCoJAEIbvPYXYZYbWyKLTWk8SiKyNDegq7ixB0au3rXUw6vbx8fEzjMkaY8KSrWl9fU4KJzX368txMaumG6IIBBbv3XArJSEleiK2LEA4s3zYnaX0DKRy1NSPwFYSPuSai4N9B51vPwEpXq3wu9rOVVXXUyVThWoyvZfSyQjxyogq3yhBNXhxkKb4ntKP0FVsAe8Lgh3qYYyzBOnJpqij2v@rbf7rHuFpqK0aF7JryNr4gBc)

Comment: I think you must include both #includes in source unfortunately

Comment: [150 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZY1BCsIwEEX3PYVUhAxNxCqupnoQEUpJTR1o0tCmCJZe3ZhU3Ohu5v3/@FI0Unq/Jm273hWNttv7OSFUzMCk7bN0K8UdxosMuYGFj@8A6WRQdT2LwXBz5UghyQMX@VLWY/thipMQAEsZKcsKg2GktD0Zp1i6udRXk3IHEK2qrqPlogU4e12RYTAlih0Av0roAwZ0/Ef7/JfN/iVVWzWDFw8v2jD9Bg "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 55 bytes

```scala
n=>{val a=(1 to n).map(BigInt(_));a.map(_+1+a.product)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZVFNT-MwEBXX_oonqwdbDVWTtpRmlUrAiQMn2FOpKm-alLLtpMTmS1V_CZdelgt3_gv8GsZOila7ljKTmffm49kvrybVS919G4tDKh51SWLy0Sp-3WapxYVeEDYN4EEvkceQ52ST0WV2Nz5dzPl_opD8ubf54fHHgJLRxtF0IkPYAqTaK72WFVFOlfqhfWLaClu6vS6L2X1q1bYq_zx4B2ZZjhVPlLqcmxgnZamfx5e2XNB8omL8pIVF4tepFrKZsWfaZIazvJP0ACC7gQ-PAwwDhB2lgj3Sr5AwihiIus70nOk7c_QXMQoDNk5GFFU6npCMUIsR_bAz7Ax7UTgIB-x7HT5CoYUnpXwL1fDue8N2XpSZTm-wQcoxJAV41GT5_kb1TKdoXjiFuSRVJ9cs3i5JGkFJc0Nb8S_AFe3V7-qSpLgmofYMbUxWWulbJn5YAG4To0mMcjq-JtSnyeF_rY244vWxdo1mYAHwxTVv23Bf_Xy7XeW_AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 15 bytes

```
n->[n!+2..n!+n]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboW6_N07aLzFLWN9PSAZF4sRPSmTmJBQU6lRoWCrp1CQVFmXgmQqQTiKCmkaVRoauooRBvrKJjqKBgZxmpC9CxYAKEB)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 13 bytes

```
#!+2~Range~#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X1lR26guKDEvPbVOWe1/QFFmXomCQ3q0kWHs//8A)

Comment: does wolfram alpha have a similar formula? thanks

Comment: @vengy you can use something like `21!+k for k=2..21`

Comment: That [example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=21%21%2Bk+for+k%3D2..21) worked nicely. Thanks!

Comment: Actually this works too: `21!+k,k=2..21`

Comment: @vengy or `21!+{2..21}`

Comment: That's a winner! Might be useful to put it as a separate answer?

Comment: this is not a function. the input is hardcoded...

Comment: Good point.....

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 43 bytes

```
.+
*
v`__+
$.&$*
L$`\d+
$$.($&*_$=
%~`^
.+¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0@bS4urLCE@XptLRU9NRYvLRyUhJgXIUdHTUFHTilex5VKtS4jj0tM@tO3/fyNDAA) Outputs the numbers in descending order. Explanation:

```
.+
*
```

Convert `n` to unary.

```
v`__+
$.&$*
```

Create an expression `n*...*3*2*` that evaluates to `n!` in unary.

```
L$`\d+
$$.($&*_$=
```

For each integer in that expression, create an expression that adds `i` and converts to decimal.

```
%~`^
.+¶
```

Evaluate each resulting expression.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 11 bytes

```
≔…·²ＮθＩ⁺θΠθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dco7DoAgDADQ3VMwlgQHWZ2Mk4sh3qAiURKs8vP6lTc/e2GyDwbmKWd/EixkQ83@cxvS6UArsdBby1rv3SWQUokox84kTwVmzAVM6xCVMOk5qi0QZTMy64H7L/w) Link is to verbose version of code.

```
≔…·²Ｎθ
```

Create a list from `2` up to `n` inclusive.

```
Ｉ⁺θΠθ
```

Vectorised add the list to its product.

Of course, the given formula is just an existence proof and there are usually lower runs. For instance, the LCM is readily proven to produce a run:

```
Ｎθ≔…·²θηＷ⌈﹪±θη≧⁺ιθＩ⁺θη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcw7DsMgEEXR3qugHCRSxC1VlMqFLcs7mBAEIwE2Pye7J45on@47ymJSO7rWpnDUslT/0gkil8MjZzIBpqBczXTqDYPRMAoWuWD2Cj6WnGYw45d89TDv7@p2WLTBoqFHnLMZjy5tZGyB9cIEo78ihzVRKPDE3HeI/SNbu4/tdrof) Link is to verbose version of code. Or more efficiently:

```
Ｎθ≔…·²θηＦη≔⌊Φ×⊖ηθ¬﹪κιθＩ⁺θη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3NDoIwEITvPEWP2wQPcuVkNCYcIMT4ArWssLHdQn94/Vqic51v5tOL8topk3PHa4pDsi/0sMm2uoRAM0PH2qRAOz4UzwhNLTZZi6UAb@cFLFL8wZ6YbLJwJxPLxZMsBrih9miRI04F/W0HF6F3UzIOPrUgWXIUbTV64ghXFSKMxQnb4ZGyzbk559Nuvg) Link is to verbose version of code.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 10, <s>134</s> 131 bytes

```java
n->{var f=n.ONE;int N=n.intValue(),i=N;for(;i>1;)f=f.multiply(n.valueOf(i--));for(;i++<N;)System.out.println(f.add(n.valueOf(i)));}
```

-3 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

Input as a `BigInteger`, outputs on separated lines to STDOUT.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##bVA9b4MwFNzzK54y2QIspVWXOmRo1aFDyRCpS5ThFWxqagzChipC/HZqUyp1iAd/6N2d767CAZOq@JpzjdbCGyozbgCUcaKTmAvIwhNgaFQBOak8nNXoPtmTKl89qBQdGMo9Ztr4zTp0KocMDKSzSQ7jgB3I1LBj9sK9KGT@7s931L0gNFZpxmXTEa4OO05lKlnda6dafSWGDQF0lEQlCaUrLIr2Gaenq3WiZk3vWNt5OW2IZFgU/0nUc6aZB1dt/6G9q9XcEqX2QcnJeXJ5viD9DRm@CCadsO4ZrXg04jtUcb6M9/FDfLebViCAYTkJ01uFkO02@pOgSzdh3fC8zqalvWn@AQ)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{                            // Method with BigInteger as parameter and no return:
  var f=n.ONE;                  //  Start `f` with BigInteger 1
  int N=n.intValue(),           //  Set `N` to the input-BigInteger as integer
  i=N;for(;i>1;)                //  Loop `i` in the range [N,1):
    f=f.multiply(n.valueOf(i)); //   Multiply `f` by `i`
  for(;i++<N;)                  //  Loop `i` again, this time in the range (1,N]:
    System.out.println(         //   Print with trailing newline:
      f.add(n.valueOf(i)));}    //    `f` + `i`
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 30 bytes

```
?:}  @\!
 (:{+ ""
*; :=;;
#(;)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/f3qpWQcEhRpFLQcOqWltBSYlLy1rBytbamktZw1rz/3/Tf/kFJZn5ecX/dVMA)

Introducing "small-loop-oriented programming" ;)

```
?    program start; take n from stdin
     let's say n = 4
     [ 4 | ]

:}   run in the order of :(:}
(:   : dup               [ 4 4 | ]
     ( decrement         [ 4 3 | ]
     : dup               [ 4 3 3 | ]
     } move to aux.stack [ 4 3 | 3 ]
     loop until the top is 0 after `decrement`
     [ 4 3 2 1 0 | 1 2 3 ]

*;   run in the order of ;*#(
#(   ; drop         [ 4 3 2 1 | 1 2 3 ]
     * mul          [ 4 3 2 | 1 2 3 ]
     # stack height [ 4 3 2 3 | 1 2 3 ]
     ( decrement    [ 4 3 2 2 | 1 2 3 ]
     loop until the top is 0 after `decrement`, i.e. stack height is 1
     [ 24 0 | 1 2 3 ]

;)   drop 0, and increment the factorial
     [ 25 | 1 2 3 ]

{+   run in the order of :=+{
:=   : dup                 [ 25 25 | 1 2 3 ]
     = swap the tops       [ 25 1 | 25 2 3 ]
     + add                 [ 26 | 25 2 3 ]
     { move from aux.stack [ 26 25 | 2 3 ]
     loop until the top is 0 after `swap the tops`
     [ 26 27 28 25 0 | 25 ]

;;   drop twice [ 26 27 28 | 25 ]

\!   run in the order of ""!\  (" is no-op)
""   ! pop and print as num
     \ print a newline
     loop until the top is zero, i.e. there is nothing left to print

@    end the program
```